# What does it mean for an entity to be detached?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Reading up upon [batch processing larger dataset in doctrine2](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/batch-processing.html), I stumble across the `clear` method.

There, this example is used:

```
<?php
$batchSize = 20;
$i = 0;
$q = $em->createQuery('select u from MyProject\Model\User u');
$iterableResult = $q->iterate();
foreach ($iterableResult as $row) {
    $user = $row[0];
    $user->increaseCredit();
    $user->calculateNewBonuses();
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $em->flush(); // Executes all updates.
        $em->clear(); // Detaches all objects from Doctrine!
    }
    ++$i;
}
$em->flush();
```

I am confused as to why the `clear` statement does what it does, and the information provided does not help me as well.

Also reading upon the code, does not help as I do not understand the intention of it.

This is what get actually called by doctrine2:

```
/**
 * Clears the UnitOfWork.
 *
 * @param string|null $entityName if given, only entities of this type will get detached.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function clear($entityName = null)
{
    if ($entityName === null) {
        $this->identityMap =
        $this->entityIdentifiers =
        $this->originalEntityData =
        $this->entityChangeSets =
        $this->entityStates =
        $this->scheduledForSynchronization =
        $this->entityInsertions =
        $this->entityUpdates =
        $this->entityDeletions =
        $this->collectionDeletions =
        $this->collectionUpdates =
        $this->extraUpdates =
        $this->readOnlyObjects =
        $this->visitedCollections =
        $this->orphanRemovals = array();

        if ($this->commitOrderCalculator !== null) {
            $this->commitOrderCalculator->clear();
        }
    } else {
        $visited = array();

        foreach ($this->identityMap as $className => $entities) {
            if ($className !== $entityName) {
                continue;
            }

            foreach ($entities as $entity) {
                $this->doDetach($entity, $visited, false);
            }
        }
    }

    if ($this->evm->hasListeners(Events::onClear)) {
        $this->evm->dispatchEvent(Events::onClear, new Event\OnClearEventArgs($this->em, $entityName));
    }
}
```

So my question is:

What does it mean for an object to be detached from doctrine? What are the implications? What are the up- and downsides of using `clear`?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the doctrine reference documentation it looks like `clear()` will effectively free the `EntityManager` of all objects it is handling.

So my understanding is that `flush()` commits to the database and `clear()` frees from memory (at least as far as doctrine is concerned).

Have a look at the docs for the `EntityManager`'s `clear()` method [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#_clear) and [here (lines 421 to 435)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.EntityManager.html#422). Which in turn call `UnitOfWork`,
So for `UnitOfWork`  have a look [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#_clear) and [here (lines 1881 an on)](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.UnitOfWork.html#1882)

Just for info, from the docs (latest 2.5 version) you get this code from the `EntityManager`:

```
 /**
  * Clears the EntityManager. All entities that are currently managed
  * by this EntityManager become detached.
  *
  * @param string $entityName
  */
 public function clear($entityName = null)
 {
     if ($entityName === null) {
         $this->unitOfWork->clear();
     } else {
         //TODO
         throw new ORMException("EntityManager#clear(\$entityName) not yet implemented.");
     }
 }
```

and for the UnitOfWork :

```
/**
  * Clears the UnitOfWork.
  */
 public function clear()
 {
     $this->identityMap =
     $this->entityIdentifiers =
     $this->originalEntityData =
     $this->entityChangeSets =
     $this->entityStates =
     $this->scheduledForDirtyCheck =
     $this->entityInsertions =
     $this->entityUpdates =
     $this->entityDeletions =
     $this->collectionDeletions =
     $this->collectionUpdates =
     $this->extraUpdates =
     $this->readOnlyObjects =
     $this->orphanRemovals = array();
     if ($this->commitOrderCalculator !== null) {
         $this->commitOrderCalculator->clear();
     }

     if ($this->evm->hasListeners(Events::onClear)) {
         $this->evm->dispatchEvent(Events::onClear, new Event\OnClearEventArgs($this->em));
     }
 }
```

So when the docs say :

> Clears the EntityManager. All entities that are currently managed by this EntityManager become detached.

**My understanding is that what they mean by "detached" is that the entity manager no longer holds record of those entities. So they can get garbage collected if nothing else refers to them.**

And if you want to make sure it does get garbage collected and effectively You're freeing up memory, then you'd better call [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php) somewhere along your `foreach` process loop.